# Build Process in Jenkins

Tags: plugins, deployment, jenkins

I am new to the JENKINS environment. I have to write a script such that 10 most recent war files are stored. The newest should be linked to the ROOT.war ( or copied ) is there a plugin which does this or if there isn't can somebody guide me on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about 10 most recent war files *that had been built by Jenkins*, then you don't need any special plugins.

Under your job configuration:

- Click **Discard Old Builds**
- Click **Advanced** button
- Under *Max # of builds to keep with artifacts*, enter **10**

This will keep the full build history, but only the last 10 artifacts will be stored. You can access your artifacts by selecting the build from the **Build History** on the left and then clicking on **Build Artifacts**

Your comment about the root.war is kind of vague. Are you asking how to deploy the latest root.war to the server? If so, please clarify your question. Nonetheless, here is a plugin to deploy .war files:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin